# Real time Google Script Form changes (triggers, onEdit())

Tags: event-handling, google-apps-script, real-time, eventtrigger, google-forms

How do you change items in Forms from user triggered events during live user interaction with the Form?

I got three ListItems in my form. They all got the same choices to choose from. Users get to choose an activity. If they don't get their choice in the first ListItem they might get it in the second or third.

When a user choose an activity from one of the three ListItems I want to remove this choice of activity from the other two ListItems so that it's not possible to choose the same activity multiple times.

How do you do this? There's an onEdit() function for Spreadsheets but what about Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The live Google Forms cannot be modified based on user interaction.

What you can do is create sections (or branches) and redirect the user to a different section based on the value they've entered in a particular field.